# Using prototype function with key event

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototype, keyup, onkeyup

I'd like to write ajax prototype function that transforms to upper every character after typing it in a formular for several input data.

```
jQuery.fn.doKeyUpToUpper = function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
}
```

and associate this function with fields :

```
$('#First').doKeyUpToUpper();
$('#Second').doKeyUpToUpper();
$('#Third').doKeyUpToUpper();
```

where First, Second and Third are

```
<input id=First value="" />
<input id=Second value="" />
<input id=Third value="" />
```

input fields...

Unfortunately, I don't know how to add keyup event to each fields.

Anyone help ?
Thanks

Comment: PS : Not sure about doKeyUpToUpper function code, but that's not the point. Idea is here.

Comment: So, you might want to look into the native event `onkeyup/onkeypress`. You don't need to recreate them with jQuery, but you can do something like `$('#first, #second, #third').on('keyup', () => { this.value = this.value.toUpperCase() }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You where well on your way. But only defined the behaviour on "keyup" and didn't actually set the event.

```js
jQuery.fn.doKeyUpToUpper = function () {
  $(this).on('keyup', function () {
    $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
  });
};

// or a more dynamic alternative
jQuery.fn.toUpperOn = function (event) {
  $(this).on(event, function () {
    $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
  });
};

// based upon the question in the comments
jQuery.fn.toUpperOn = function (event, callback) {
  $(this).on(event, function () {
    $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
    if (callback) callback.apply(this, arguments);
  });
};

$("#first").doKeyUpToUpper();
$("#second").toUpperOn('keyup');
$("#third").toUpperOn('keyup', function (event) {
  console.log(this.id, this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="first" type="text" />
<input id="second" type="text" />
<input id="third" type="text" />
```

Have a look at the [`jQuery.on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) documentation for more details.

Comment: Thanks ! Another question : Let say I need to trace which field is processed by the function, using console.log(), how should I do ?

Comment: @BartmanDilaw You can add a callback to the function definition so you can run things like `console.log()`. See my updated answer.